# How can I prove that a 3x3 symmetric matrix has eigenvalue = 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I need to prove that a non-zero **Symmetric** Matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 & ab & ac \\
    ab & b^2 & bc \\
    ac & bc & c^2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
has an eigenvalue = 1.

So for any non-zero vector 
$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ z \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

The following equation is true:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    a^2 & ab & ac \\
    ab & b^2 & bc \\
    ac & bc & c^2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ z \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\ y \\ z \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not for any non-zero vector, rather, for some non-zero vector (an eigenvector associated to that eigenvalue).

Comment: having eigenvalue 1 means that the equation $(M-1 Id)v=0$ has a solution for some  vectro $v$,  i.e. the determinant of $(M-1 Id)$ must be 0

Comment: Note that your matrix has rank $1$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. What is the relation between the rank 1 and eigenvalue=1?

Comment: It's not directly related, but knowing the rank can help finding the eigenvalues.

Comment: Regarding rank 1 and eigenvalues: since the matrix equals $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$, what do you get if you multiply it by the vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. The number $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, since the characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $(a^2+b^2+c^2)x^2-x^3$. Besides, asserting that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ means that there is **some** non-zero vector $v$ such that $M.v=v$.

Comment: Thanks very much, would you please give a full mathematical justification or a reference so I can accept your answer. Just a side note: I was trying to prove that there is not eigenvector = 1 (i.e. Reductio ad absurdum)

Comment: A reference for what? For the fact that the characteristic polynomial is $(a^2+b^2+c^2)x^2-x^3$? I simply computed it. Or a reference for the fact that the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial? That's part of any Linear Algebra textbook.

Comment: Okay got it. So as long as $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$  doesn't equal 1, the above equation is incorrect, is that right?

Comment: No. As long as $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq1$, the number $1$ is not a root of that equation.

Comment: but you said *The number 1 is an eigenvalue of M if and only if a2+b2+c2=1*

Comment: Yes, I said that. when you wrote that “the above equation is incorrect”, which equation did you have in mind?

Comment: A mathematician told me that to prove the above equation "M.V=V" is not true I should prove that the matrix M has no eigenvalue=1

Comment: So you mean the equation$$\begin{bmatrix}    a^2 & ab & ac \\    ab & b^2 & bc \\    ac & bc & c^2 \\    \end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}    x \\ y \\ z \\    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}    x \\ y \\ z \\    \end{bmatrix}.$$If $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq1$, it has no non-zero  solutions.

Comment: Exactly! That what I meant

Comment: I think there is a mistake (correct me please if I'm wrong), shouldn't it be: Eigenvector =1 if only and only if $$a^2=b^2=c^2=1$$ ??

Comment: No. It's as I wrote it. The characteristic polynomial is $(a^2+b^2+c^2)x^2-x^3$ and asserting that $1$ is a root of this polynomial means that $a^2+b^2+c^2-1=0$, which is equivalent to $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: Now I really need a reference please, I am using [this](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/MtrxVibe/EigMat/MatrixEigen.html) reference... $$|A-λ·I|=0$$

Comment: I suggest that you use [this one](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/20_spring_05/handouts/ch05_notes.pdf) instead.